# Fit background image in all screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a login page where the footer has an image. There are login options for some users where they can login using options other than username and password such as "Facebook", "Yahoo" and "Google" - it can be seen in image1 below.

[image]

There is an image below the login options(i.e. below sign-in options of "Facebook", "Yahoo" and "Google") The image fits in perfectly fine when the sign-in options of "Facebook", "Yahoo" and "Google" are present. However, the image moves up when the sign-in options of "Facebook", "Yahoo" and "Google" are removed for some users. It leaves an empty space at the bottom. Below is the picture. I have used background-size:contain and cover and tried to find a solution but the image either overflows or cuts down. I can adjust the height and fit the image but that creates problem in other screen sizes. **How can I fit the image perferctly making it responsive to collapse and expand depending on whether login options are presesnt or not.** Many thanks for all the help. Below is the code as well.

[image]

```css
.footer {
    background-image: url('../img/modeler-footer-tablet2.jpg');
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 15%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 15%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}


.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
}

    div.footer {
        width: 100vw;
        max-height: 37vh;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer footer-content">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Normally you'd use `cover` to make the image always fill the whole available space. Depending on the aspect ratio, some parts of the image will be cut off. Your image has to be designed in such a way that this is not a problem.

Comment: Always use the right element, semantics. In your case, use `<footer>` in place of `<div class=footer>`. Then for the CSS just do `body > footer {background-size: cover; }`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `object-fit: cover` and also positioning footer as an `absolute` to a page, so it won't move in case some content above will change.

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: // your height;
  background-image: url(); // your image url
  object-fit: cover;
}
```